# À la main vs à sa main

Tags: articles, possessif, articles-definis

> Elle a mal à la main.
>
> Elle a mal à sa main.

Je crois qu'avec parties du corps l'on emploie l'article défini.
Cependant, je me demande quand l'on peut employer le déterminant possessif et quelle est la différence entre les deux phrases ci-dessus (s'il y en a une).

Comment: « voir de ***ses/mes/tes propres yeux*** quelque chose », « faire quelque chose de ***ses/mes/tes propres mains*** », etc. Il suffit de mettre un adjectif épithète comme « propre » pour choisir par défaut des pronoms possessifs « ses/mes/tes ».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si on parle d'une partie de son propre corps, la règle est d'utiliser l'article défini, et éventuellement un pronom réfléchi avec le verbe (ce qui n'est pas possible dans votre exemple):

> Elle a mal à la main
>
> Elle s'est brossé les dents

L'usage d'un adjectif possessif pour parler d'une partie de son propre corps peut être entendu en langage familier, mais c'est généralement considéré comme une faute, du genre que les professeurs reprennent chez les enfants.

Exception: si on met un adjectif épithète avec la partie du corps, on met un adjectif possessif.

> Elle a brossé ses longs cheveux blonds (et non *elle s'est brossé les longs cheveux blonds*)

Exception à l'exception: si l'adjectif est *droit* ou *gauche*.

> Elle s'est fait mal à la main gauche

Comment: Je vous remercie de votre réponse. Si l'on parle donc correctement l'usage du déterminant possessif dans cet exemple est incorrect, non ?

Comment: Oui - on pourra l'entendre dans la rue, mais ce n'est pas du "beau" français.