# B. se tourne et pose la / une main sur mon épaule

Tags: articles, déterminants

> B. se tourne et pose **la** main sur mon épaule.
>
> B. se tourne et pose **une** main sur mon épaule.

Selon ces deux fils, ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24149/adjectif-possessif-ou-article-d%C3%A9fini/24154#24154)) et ([2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30522/%C3%80-la-main-vs-%C3%A0-sa-main)), *pose **la** main* est meilleur que *pose **sa** main* dans la première phrase. Mais je vois aussi des exemples avec *pose **une** main* sur Internet. Donc, la deuxième phrase serait-elle aussi possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Les trois phrases peuvent se dire/lire mais je trouve la forme « [...] pose **sa** main **sur** mon épaule » la plus naturelle et pertinente par la combinaison des deux possessifs.

Comment: Dans le premier lien, dans la 1ère réponse, il dit que l'article définitif est le meilleur choix. _Il lève la tête. (Et pas "sa tête")_ Sais-tu pourquoi dans ma phrase "sa" est préférable à "la" ? Est-ce un choix subjectif ? Ou en raison de la combinaison des deux possessifs ?

Comment: *Il lève sa tête* n'est pas impossible, mais comme il n'a qu'une tête, *la* suffit, on sait de quelle tête il s'agit. On dirait en revanche *il approche sa tête de la mienne* plutôt que *il approche la tête de la mienne* qui me semble exclu.

Comment: OK, merci. Et si je dis _Il pose sa / la main sur la table_, est-ce que "la" est préférable à cause de _**la** table_ ? Ou "sa" ?

Comment: Là, je dirais que c'est *kif-kif*.